# Scala generic type inference inconsistent with ClassTag

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm using Scala 2.10, and have found what I consider weird behaviour when using type inference for generic parameters. Consider the example below (note `i` is just a dummy variable):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.{ClassTag,classTag}
     |
     | def broken[T : ClassTag](i : Int) : List[T] = {
     |   println("ClassTag is : " + classTag[T])
     |   List.empty[T]
     | }

import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

broken: [T](i: Int)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])List[T]

scala> broken(3)
ClassTag is : Nothing
res0: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> val brokenVal : List[String] = broken(3)
ClassTag is : Nothing
brokenVal: List[String] = List()
```

The call `broken(3)` seems consistent, in that the print statement inside the function agrees with the inferred `ClassTag`.

However, the second statement, there is an inconsistency between what the compiler infers for the `ClassTag`, and is printed inside the function, and what the actual return type is.

I would have expected the compiler to infer the `ClassTag` from the type declaration i.e. `List[String]`. Is this not correct? Can somebody enlighten me?

Some further context here: I'm actually using the classtag to filter a collection in some code (not shown here), and it's obviously failing when I don't specify `T` explicitly, as it's comparing against type `Nothing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual *return* type for your second example is `List[Nothing]`, so the `ClassTag` is perfectly consistent with it. This happens because the `List` is covariant (defined as `List[+A]` instead of just `List[A]`). This covariance allows you to write statements like `list = Nil` (because `Nil.type = List[Nothing]`), but it also allows compiler to infer bottom type as list type argument, because `List[Nothing]` is subtype of `List[String]`, again, due to it's covariance. So the actual type mismatch is between the return type and the type of `brokenVal`.

To overcome this limitation, you might use a invariant type as your return type, i.e.:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Invariant[T]

def f[T: ClassTag](i: Int): Invariant[T] = {
  println("ClassTag: " + implicitly[ClassTag[T]])
  new Invariant[T]
}

val ret: Invariant[String] = f(3)
// ClassTag: java.lang.String
// ret: Invariant[String] = Invariant@30af5b6b
```

On other side, you might let compiler to infer `T` from something else, for example, by passing a value of type `T` as argument. You cannot make this example work on vanilla `List`s, because you cannot change variance of them.

Comment: I was in fact using rx Observables, which are also covariant, and running into this problem. I was using the ClassTag in a `collect` statement to pick up only items of a certain type. As I'm using the type itself to filter stuff out i.e. `observable collect { case t : T => t }` there's no value to pass in as an argument, which like you say would have fixed the inference problem. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: There is a possible macro solution to collect type signature even in this situation, but I think that it's overkill to use macros here. Just omit variable type and specify `[T]` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to use `NotNothing` type class to ensure compile time type safety.

as explained here [Possible to make scala require a non-Nothing generic method parameter and return to type-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403287/possible-to-make-scala-require-a-non-nothing-generic-method-parameter-and-return)

scalaZ has a `NotNothing` class that you can use.

```
def broken[T : ClassTag : NotNothing](i : Int) : List[T] = {
  println("ClassTag is : " + classTag[T])
  List.empty[T]
}
```